# Why is .NET2.0 referenced in a .cache file, when the project is .NET 4.5.2?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, migration

I had a .NET 2.0 project that I migrated to .NET 4.5.2.

When I build the migrated project, .cache files are generated and they contain values "v2.0.50727" all over it.

There are no references to .NET 2.0 in my project, did I miss something? Where does "v2.0.50727" come from if it's not reference in my project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in an ASP.NET environment or in a desktop one?

If in a ASP.NET the IIS POOL may be set as NET 2.0 instead 4.0.

If in a desktop environment, some utilized control may be really using a .NET 2.0 version - or even, you may loading via IMPORTS/USING some old Assembly in some module or class.

Another thing: did you modified the PROJECT SETTINGS?